# Is it safe to develop a small portal in Django

Tags: django, ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, yii, web-frameworks

Actually these are 3 questions. I once developed a site using an open source, that use smarty. But then after going inside a code, I think if it was in some better and agile framework then I can update code much easily without spending much time. At the same time I wanted to come to some thing else than PHP, to improve my skillset also. Actually I do better work when I enjoy some thing. I enjoyed working in django and RoR. I am new to both. I worked in both and like RoR although my Python is better than Ruby. I saw Yii as a better framework but neither its documentation is very good as compared to RoR or Django and it will be still PHP so no big improvement in skillset.

I selected Rails, but I am even stopping many time during just installation and configuration of Rails. And I found that although rails is elder than Django but python community seems much more active than rails. I just tried Django and there were new things but I didn't find any barrier while doing tutorials. It was very good, although some thing were not according to how I liked but much better. The problem with django is that it is in Python 2.x so I think when it will be ported to Python 3 then I will need to shift my work to python 3 also. So I want to know that how much percent I will need to redo my work. As it is on the Django framework and not at low level. So will my code automatically portable? And when will I need to do? I guess this summer? Or is it some thing better that is agile, scalable, enjoyable and easy to deploy as I think Django hosting is also on less server but same can be case with any JVM based platform?

So what you guys think, Please tell whether should I go with django or rails or Yii or some thing else like grails or wicket??? Please tell in the light of above mentioned factors

thanks everyone for your advises in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did php for ages switched to rails / if you want todo it in php > look at zend framework or symphony

rails is great special if you have some backend stuff todo > active admin / rails admin speed up development

django is nice but way harder to deploy if you ask me

so in my case if your skill set is at PHP and you need to get it done quick > zend_framework
rails isnt that complicated as soon as you understand the differences .. > you know how coding works .. just syntax is different .. rails gives a HUGE BOOST in productivity due the generators / if you know how to use them railscast is a super place to get hocked

so my opinion : if you need to get it done quickly with skills you already got > Zend Framework

Experimental and Realy sexy to code > rails

cheers Pierre